# Facebook debugger response code 302

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, response.redirect, facebook-sharer, http-status-code-302

looks like that facebook scraper cant detect my page, it says that the

> response code is : 302

and when I click to see what scraper sees from my URL link, it says:

> Document returned no data

I already have all the og meta tags along canonical URL link working fine, I guess it must be some redirection issue since the response code indicate it. it's the same error on my homepage and other pages.

because of this, I cant share any content of my website via sharing a URL on facebook.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Your site redirects to itself – which creates an endless loop, even when I try to access it in my browser.

Comment: Thanks for your comment CBore, But how's that possible? I run my website on nginx, could it be a rewrite issue? how can I fix it? and how did you test it with your browser? can you please explain it so I can check it over here too?

Comment: I've got a similiar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824651/facebook-sharer-object-moved-302-error - Has anyone got a solution?

Comment: my issue was with the server configuration and it's redirection, I'm not sure what's your problem exactly but maybe try this website to figure it out: http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/ , make sure to check both with WWW and without it.