# Facebook sharer: Object moved/302 error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, iis, facebook-sharer, http-status-code-302

I get a ̀`Object moved` message when sharing URLs from my site on facebook. Facebook debugger tells me that he sees an http response `302` he can't follow:

```
URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.
```

But in the browser I get a `200` for the same URL.

When I try to rescrape, I get the following error:

```
Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.
```

This question has been asked quite a few times, but I've not come accross an answer. The website runs with sitecore/IIS and is available via HTTP only (no HTTPS, if that's relevant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as obvious as described in the question:
We had special code in our site that caused redirects for some clients (non-germans), so our browser got a 200 and Facebook a 302.

For anyone stumbling upon this question and looking for help, the best answer I found after a long search (not top on google) was given to the following question:

[Facebook won't share a link to my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185406/facebook-wont-share-a-link-to-my-site)

Answer (score 1):

I had a simillar issue with the server configuration and it's redirection 301 & 302, I'm not sure what's your problem exactly but maybe try [this website](http://internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check) to figure it out, make sure to check both with WWW and without it.

one must be a permanent 301 redirect, and the other one must be a direct link, for instance without WWW must be redirected to WWW, and the WWW one shouldn't be redirected at all.